# WCF Bind Transport protocols confusion

Tags: wcf, networking

In Wcf , there are many types of bindings for tranferring the messages.(HTTPBinding and TCP binding). But to the knowledge I learn from university, TCP is on the transport layer, so if we use TCP binding, what is the application layer protocol?

Comment: It is a secret - Microsoft proprietary protocol. It is not an open standard - hence not inter-operable.

Comment: So if I use HTTPBinding, what will be the transport layer protocol? TCP, UDP?

Comment: HTTP always uses TCP at transport layer.

Comment: @YK1 - TCP is not, to the best of my knowledge, Microsoft proprietary. It is an open standard.  Microsoft may have their own implementation of it, but the standard is well known and documented.

Comment: @Tim: I am not saying TCP is proprietary. I am saying WCF net.tcp  application layer implementation is proprietary.

Comment: Thanks, all clear now :)